# Splicing 6 AWG Wire

Tags: electrical, wiring

In my heater installation I need to connect two sets of 6 awg wire and a ground on a 50 amp circuit.[image: Here's the connection instructions]

Whatever I use to splice is going to have to fit thru the hole and go into the wiring compartment. My initial thought is to use a blue nut and tape, but I also see butt connectors, Polaris Taps and other options.

My other thought is to take off the back of the unit and connect the wires directly to whatever the pigtails are attached to, removing the pigtails.

What would you do?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

EDIT: I ended up getting two of these:

[Morris Products Insulated 2 Conductor Splice Connector](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B005FMQ5UW)

Comment: The wires for the power supply should stick out from the conduit by ~6 inches.  Wires from the heater are as long.  That big window should be plenty to attach your favourite connectors in.

Comment: Thanks, what would you recommend to connect the wires?

Comment: Wire nuts of the right size should be okay.  You want a size of nut with two 6 gauge wire around the centre of range of sizes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The picture is misleading. The text is comparatively clear.

The hole the wires come out through in the picture is the knock-out where the cable or conduit goes into the device. The wires get shoved back in there before that happens (or are not ever pulled out through it, more likely.) A suitable clamp or fitting is used to secure the cable or conduit.

The large rectangular hole ("watch window for wiring") to the left and above that is where you pull the supply wires and the device wires to be joined out to actually make the connection and put the connected wires back inside the device, before restoring the cover (not shown in picture.) That hole will easily fit any listed and approved splicing device you choose to use, in triplicate.

Comment: Thanks, that helps a ton...what would you connect the wires with? Is a cap and tape sufficient for 6 awg / 50 amps?

Comment: If you **need** tape to keep a wire-nut/Marrette ("cap") on the wires, **don't** use wire-nuts/Marrettes at all. If they fall off otherwise, they are not correctly tightened. If bare wire is sticking out, the strip length is incorrect. If you use the correct size, applied correctly, they work fine for 50A and 6 AWG. If your past experience leads you to reach for the tape, Polaris or Mac-block connectors and a torque driver might be well worth the extra cost, given the savings on "electrical fires not started"

Comment: Thanks again, I ended up getting the Morris Products Connectors I linked in my OP. Seems safe and simple, and was only 25 bucks.